# Applying CSS style to Raphaël path elements using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, raphael

I'm drawing a shape using Raphaël JS's path element. I want to apply a background image to this element using jQuery. Here's what I tried

```
leaf = paper.path("M"+leafStartPoint+" c0,0 -30,0 -30,-30 c0,0 0,-10 5,-20 c0,0 10,-10 15,-40 c0,0 5,25 20,35 c0,0 20,10 20,25 c0,0 0,30 -30,30z");

($(leaf.node)).css('background-image', 'url(blackdot.jpg)');
```

But it doesn't work. It's working fine when I try applying styles to Raphaël text elements. Is there any workaround to this problem?